# PHP: Make directory that only allows reading of files

Tags: php, upload, permissions, mkdir

I want to use the mkdir() function that will allow me to fetch images from that directory to be added to my html/php pages but nothing in that directory should be executable (because I am allowing image uploads into that directory)... so even if someone manages to get past my security checks and uploads a .php file there it should not be able to run.

What permissions / options should I use with mkdir() to do so?

I understand this can also be done with a .htaccess file, if you can answer with the mkdir and  the .htaccess file code I would really appreciate it!

Thanks in advance!

Comment: what do you mean by this? what value is to be set in `mkdir()`? you mean the octal values?

Comment: No, I mean the mode values, for example the default is "0777"

Comment: yes that is the octal values :)

Comment: Ah ok, didnt know it was called octal as well :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well you could just use this as reference:

```
octal number to represent mode/permission:
r: 4
w: 2
x: 1

Read, write and execute (full) 
0+r+w+x = 0+4+2+1 = 7

Only Read and write permission on a file in octal is
0+r+w+x = 0+4+2+0 = 6

Only read and execute permission on a file in octal is
0+r+w+x = 0+4+0+1 = 5

User = r+w+x = 0+4+2+1 = 7
Group= r+w+x = 0+4+2+0 = 6
Others = r+w+x = 0+0+0+1 = 1
```

Then use it according in `mkdir()`:

```
mkdir('path/to/directory/', 0555); // read execute / 444 readonly
```

If this still didn't work, you can explicitly use `chmod()` for it:

```
chmod('/directory/', 0555);
```

Comment: Will try it and come back :)
Any idea about the htaccess file?

Comment: @Ryan sorry i don't have the answer on that part